# sql server Возможно ли задать свою кодировку для поля varchar?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Одно из текстовых полей может содержать китайские символы. Возможно ли настроить кодировку для поля не меняя кодировку для бд в целом?
пробовал

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[uploadLog]
ALTER COLUMN [filename] nvarchar(MAX) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS;
```

но это не помогло. ??? вместо иероглифов
Данные сохраняются с помощью entity framework.